# SSRS Validate User Input Length

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to validate the user input length in a report, it should be integer and 16 digits long. Is is possible to validate on the client side ?

Comment: By "user input length" do you mean a parameter you are passing to the report?  Is the client using the SSRS report viewer or something else?

Comment: Yes, Correct, passing to the report. For example, user puts 16 digits empID, and database returns related data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Step 1:  Use report designer or VS and set the parameter type to int;
  this will ensure that only integers are accepted.
- Step 2:
- Option 1: 
  Create a 2nd dataset that accepts the inital parameter as input and
  queries the datasource for a valid employee id.  If there is no
  match, you could return an "invalid employee #" type message.  If
  there is a match, use the returned value as a parameter for the main
  query.
- Option 2:  Use the Code section of report builder to return a
  true/false boolean based on the length of the initial supplied
  parameter. Something like this (this is untested because I'm not a VB
  developer):

> ```
> 1:  'Invalidates the duration between the start date and end date
> 2:  Function ValidateParam(Parameter) as Boolean
> 3:      If LEN(CSTR(Parameter)) = 16 Then
> 5:          Return"True"
> 6:      Else
> 7:          Return "False"
> 8:      End if
> 9:  End Function
> ```

You can then hide or show an error message text box based on this function.
Like [this.](http://geekswithblogs.net/Compudicted/archive/2012/08/14/validate-ssrs-report-input-parameters-the-proper-way.aspx)

Comment: Hi, I tried you method. Basically, I put it in the code section. But when I tried to use it like "Code.ValidateParam(Parameters!EmpID.Value)" it can not find the function "ValidateParam"